# Display issues with NVIDIA K2100M

Tags: graphics-card

Windows 8.1 x64:

In Chrome, on the laptop display I see everything fine:

[image]

Move over to extended display and I get this:

[image]

Dell UP2414Q Monitor at 3840 x 2160.  Have tried different cables, different monitors, updated NVIDIA drivers, turning clear text on/off changing font size in windows.  Nothing seems to fix it.  Any ideas?

BTW, it's just the tab bar, rest of the page looks fine.

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug rather than a GPU issue, try filing a bug on their bugtracker. By the way, I get a similar issue on Firefox with my Intel card, and it's indeed a bug in the browser (referenced on the bugtracker but sadly not fixed yet).